# RuntimeError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: invalid argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to run tensorflow-gpu on Windows 10 on a Laptop with a Quadro GPU

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.21       Driver Version: 465.21       CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro T2000       WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   59C    P0    14W /  N/A |   2708MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

when trying to verify whether everything works fine I found that
device_lib.list_local_devices() fails with

```
**RuntimeError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: invalid argument**


2021-01-13 11:30:14.735823: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: Quadro T2000 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.5GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 104.34GiB/s
2021-01-13 11:30:14.736173: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library
cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-13 11:30:14.736376: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library
cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-13 11:30:14.736590: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library
cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-13 11:30:14.736801: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library
cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-13 11:30:14.737016: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library
curand64_10.dll
2021-01-13 11:30:14.737221: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library
cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-13 11:30:14.737418: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library
cusparse64_11.dll
2021-01-13 11:30:14.737590: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library
cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-13 11:30:14.737787: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\D041705\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\device_lib.py", line
43, in list_local_devices
    _convert(s) for s in _pywrap_device_lib.list_devices(serialized_config)
RuntimeError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: invalid argument
```

Any hints way that happens?
I have CUDA 11.2 python 3.8.7 and I installed the latest packages for tf and tf-gpu

Answer (score 2):

Just solved this problem. I supposed the universal solution is downgrading your CUDA and GPU driver version.

---

First, according to the latest [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46093), TensorFlow 2.4 is not compatible with Cuda 11.2 or 11.1, using Cuda 11.0 instead.

Second, if you are using the latest GPU driver, you will found the CUDA Version is 11.3 while running `nvidia-smi`. Downgrading GPU driver to an old version,
461.09 worked in my case.

---

1. Win10 20H2
2. GTX1070m
3. tensorflow '2.4.1'

> nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 461.09       Driver Version: 461.09       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

and

> nvcc -V

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_22_19:09:35_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.221
Build cuda_11.0_bu.relgpu_drvr445TC445_37.28845127_0
```

To test if Cuda is working, you should use Tensorflow for calculation, list devices may not help.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```

output:

```
Executing op MatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```